# Master Theorem Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I need to solve the following: $T(n)=T(n-1)+8$

I've tried doing $a=1$, $b=-1$, and $d=8$ but $\log_{-1}1$ doesn't make sense.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Where are the letters $a,b,d$ coming from, what do they represent, do you expect us to read your mind, where are you getting $\log_{-1}1$ from? Try figuring out the first few terms of the sequence by hand in terms of $T(0)$, you should find it enlightening (assuming you typed it correctly; the problem seems quite simple and you seem to be referencing something more sophisticated, which is a bit strange).

Comment: That is not a recurrence of the form acceptable for the Master Theorem, at least according to the form of Wikipedia.  You need the recurrence to be of the form $T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)$.  But, you have a $T(n-1)$ instead of $T(n/(-1))$ in your expression.  The master theorem does not apply.

Comment: Furthermore, [Ramanujan's Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem) refers to something totally different than this Master Theorem.  (I've re-tagged for you.)

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to apply Master Theorem.

You have

$$T(n) = T(n-1) + 8 = \left(T(n-2)+8\right) + 8 = \ldots = \left(\left(T(0)+8\right)\ldots+8\right)+8 = T(0) + n\cdot8 $$